# java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException while trying to delete a renamed directory(Using Files.move)

Tags: java, windows, azul-zulu

I'm using eclipse jetty as a web container and the application is served in windows environment.The client and server consumes *javax.websocket* for communication.Client will simply send a source zip from linux environment to windows environment and after building the source in windows environment, output zip will be sent back to linux environment.

On every successful build, the output executable will be created under Release directory. For example:

> D:\Build\26-09-2020\foo\Release\donate.exe

And then the file will be moved to output directory and eventually the contents of the output directory will be sent back to client. Below is an example of output directory structure.

> D:\build\26-09-2020\foo\wintask_output

Everything worked fine without any issues but when i tried to delete the build directory (i.e)

> D:\build\26-09-2020

The contents were removed but the directory structure resides in the machine until restarting jetty server. Below is the sample error thrown by windows on deleting build directory.

[error thrown by windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMS0R.jpg)

Below is the code used for moving **donate.exe** from release directory to output directory:

```
    private boolean moveFileOrDirectory(String src, String target) {

        Path source = Paths.get(src);
        Path destination = Paths.get(target);
        Boolean isMoved = false;
        int relay = 0;

        if (Files.notExists(source)) {
            logger.info("source directory '" + source + "' doesn't exist, ignoring move action");
            return true;
        }

        while (!isMoved && relay < 20) {

            try {

                Files.move(source, destination, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                isMoved = true;
                break;

            } catch (Exception e) {

                logger.trace(
                        ":: This exception will be taken as granted beecause windows/antivirus may held the files while renaming :: Exception",
                        e);

            }
            
            relay++;

        }

        if (!isMoved) {

            logger.trace("Cannot move directories using java attempting to move as native command");
            String CommandLine = "-noprofile" + " " + "-nologo" + " " + "-noninteractive" + " " + "-Command" + " "
                    + "Rename-Item" + " " + io.surroundWithDoubleQuotes(source.toString()) + " "
                    + io.surroundWithDoubleQuotes(destination.toString());
            io.executeNativeCommand(Constants.POWER_SHELL_EXECUTABLE, CommandLine, this.WorkDirectory,
                    this.WorkDirectory + pathSep + "renameFolder.txt", false);
        }

        if (Files.exists(destination)) {
            
            logger.trace("Directory/File renamed from '" + source + "' to '"+destination+"'.");
            isMoved = true;
        }

        return isMoved;
        

        
    }
```

And even i tried to to remove the old directory in my cron job(ScheduledExecutorService) and below is the exception:

```
27 Sep 2020 20:00:27 TRACE com.integ.utils.FileIO.forceDeleteDirectory() @402 - Exception while deleting directory D:\Build\26-09-2020
java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file: D:\Build\26-09-2020
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:1338) ~[commons-io-2.7.jar:2.7]
    at com.integ.utils.FileIO.forceDeleteDirectory(FileIO.java:398) [JettyStandAloneServer.jar:?]
    at com.integ.scheduledjobs.server.ScheduledTasks.deleteOneDayOlderDirectories(ScheduledTasks.java:31) [JettyStandAloneServer.jar:?]
    at com.integ.scheduledjobs.server.ScheduledTasks.run(ScheduledTasks.java:50) [JettyStandAloneServer.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: D:\Build\26-09-2020\foo
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:89) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsDirectoryStream.<init>(WindowsDirectoryStream.java:86) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newDirectoryStream(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:523) ~[?:?]
    at java.nio.file.Files.newDirectoryStream(Files.java:471) ~[?:?]
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.visit(FileTreeWalker.java:300) ~[?:?]
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.next(FileTreeWalker.java:373) ~[?:?]
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2760) ~[?:?]
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2796) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.commons.io.file.PathUtils.visitFileTree(PathUtils.java:535) ~[commons-io-2.7.jar:2.7]
    at org.apache.commons.io.file.PathUtils.deleteDirectory(PathUtils.java:265) ~[commons-io-2.7.jar:2.7]
    at org.apache.commons.io.file.PathUtils.delete(PathUtils.java:254) ~[commons-io-2.7.jar:2.7]
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:1336) ~[commons-io-2.7.jar:2.7]
    ... 9 more
```

Below is the main program for jetty server start-up and as well as websocket integration:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.List;
import javax.websocket.Decoder;
import javax.websocket.Encoder;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpointConfig;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.server.deploy.WebSocketServerContainerInitializer;
import org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer;
import com.integ.commons.Constants;
import com.integ.jetty.filters.TokenFilter;
import com.integ.scheduledjobs.server.Cron;


import static javax.servlet.DispatcherType.REQUEST;

public class Initservice
{
    
     private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Initservice.class.getName());
    
      
    public static Server createServer(int port)
    {
        Server server = new Server(port);
        
        ServletContextHandler servletContextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        servletContextHandler.setContextPath("/");
        servletContextHandler.addServlet(DefaultServlet.class, "/");
        servletContextHandler.addFilter(TokenFilter.class, "/*", EnumSet.of(REQUEST));
        
        ServletHolder servletHolder = servletContextHandler.addServlet(ServletContainer.class, "/api/*");
        
        
        server.setHandler(servletContextHandler);
        servletHolder.setInitOrder(0);
        servletHolder.setInitParameter(
                "jersey.config.server.provider.packages",
                "com.integ.rest"
        );
        
    
        try
        {
            // Initialize javax.websocket layer
            ServerContainer wscontainer = WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.configureContext(servletContextHandler);

            // Add WebSocket endpoint to javax.websocket layer
            wscontainer.setDefaultMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize(65565555);
            wscontainer.setDefaultMaxTextMessageBufferSize(65565555);
            wscontainer.setDefaultMaxSessionIdleTimeout(0);

            
            ServerEndpointConfig config = ServerEndpointConfig.Builder.create(WsServer.class, "/events").build(); 
            wscontainer.addEndpoint(config);

            
        }
        catch (Throwable t)
        {
            t.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
        
        
        
       
        return server;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
    
        int port =  Constants.Port;
        Server server = createServer(port);
        Cron scheduledjobs = new Cron();
        try {
        scheduledjobs.startScheduledServices();
        server.start();
        server.join();
        
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            
            logger.error("Error While starting jetty server");
            logger.log(Level.ERROR, ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } finally {
            
             server.stop();
             server.destroy();
             logger.fatal("Server destroyed..");
        }
    }
}
```

> Java version - OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu11.41+23-CA (build 11.0.8+10-LTS) & Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)

> Windows version - 2019 server (10.0.17763 Build 17763)

The issue persists on directories/files where move action is performed using
`Files.move(Path source,Path target,CopyOption... options)throws IOException`

**UPDATE:**
The error is occurring only on windows environment,the same setup works fine in Linux. Is this anomaly is because of **jvm** ? because as soon as i shut down the **jvm**, the directory can be deleted from file explorer without any issues.

Any help is appreciated :-)

Comment: Windows has some unusual file locking behaviors.   Deleting files shortly after using them is rarely possible to do quickly or expediently using Java on Windows, as the file locking will get in your way.   Best advice is to ensure that all resources for that File/Path/Streams/etc are all closed properly before attempting to delete that file.   But even so, that file can be seen by Windows as still locked and not possible to be deleted (yet).

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Joakim Erdfelt. This error is happening only when i use `Files.move` and i'm pretty sure there will be no other resource holding the directory/path. 

The error is occurring only on windows environment, i have a same setup which is working fine in Linux. Is this anomaly is because of jetty? because as soon as i shut down jetty server, the directory can be deleted from file explorer without any issues.

Comment: Change that from "as soon as I shutdown Jetty" to "as soon as I shutdown the JVM" and you'll understand the problem.  It's not unique to Jetty, it's a Windows specific behavior with file locks, and is unrelated to the use of Jetty or not.  It can be any executable, even a non-java one.

Comment: Thanks,you've made that very clear! I'll update the same @Joakim Erdfelt

Comment: I've occured similiar issue with file locks on windows machine. Kicking garbage collector ( System.gc(); ) helped to get rid of locks.